# 503 service error for shipping information api in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, error

I have logged in as **USER** and at checkout end in the network seeing that for **ship information** I am getting **503 service error**. how to fix this issue.How to resolve this issue.

Request URL:

```
https://xxxxxxx/index.php/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information
```

Response

```
<html><head>
<title>503 Service Unavailable</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Service Unavailable</h1>
<p>The server is temporarily unable to service your
request due to maintenance downtime or capacity
problems. Please try again later.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: it means you have some error ,please check var/log/web_api folder

Comment: @Michael did you get any clue or solution of this issue?